# encrypting AES128-CBC on mbed microcontroller(c++) and decrypting AES128-CBC in nodejs

Tags: c++, node.js, cryptography, aes, mbed

I am receiving "Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt" when I try to decrypt a string on the nodejs side.

I do know for better security I should use a random IV and always change the IV for every new encryption and I should also implement authentication, but for the sake of understanding this and to fix the "bad decrypt" issue, I will stick to something simple. Once I can encrypt and decrypt on the mbed and nodejs, I will implement the random/changing IV and HMAC to enhance the security.

I would like to encrypt sensor data on the mbed side and decrypt the sensor data in nodejs, however, when try to decrypt the data on the nodejs side I receive the "bad decrypt" error. How do I fix the "bad decrypt" error?

mbed encrypted data:
D90E1518FF2E5D79D6F848BCB4A49BCAE3ADDC6F1D6E04265613968CFF242855C10C619C8E281A33DA690039274AA65ECAFA05631C7BB38815442E780E27E34F2B6C4B9FE1B18678077227A05ACB233D8B8A81412E584A6ECAD10397FCF36072B043F93D67B63678A5D385B402D88AF99A62E12413E7BBFDB920B51F732C0933

mbed c++ code:

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Crypto.h"
#include "MbedJSONValue.h"
#include "LinearTempSensor.h"
#include "TimeUtilities.h"
#include <string>

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

RealTimeClock rtc;

LinearTempSensor sensor(p20, 1000, LinearTempSensor::MCP9701);

//unsigned char myKEY[16] = {0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F,};
//unsigned char myIV[16] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, };
unsigned char myKEY[16] = { 'm', 'n', 'b', 'v', 'c', 'x', 'z', 'l', 'k', 'j', 'h', 'g', 'f', 'd', 's', 'a' };
unsigned char myIV[16] = { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'p', 'o', 'i', 'u', 'y', 't', 'r' };

unsigned char a[0x80] = { };

float Vout, Tav, To;

int main()
{
    pc.baud(115200);

    MbedJSONValue sensorResults;
    std::string s;

    //Create JSON
    sensorResults["Data1"][0] = "Result";
    sensorResults["Data1"][1] = 5.5;
    sensorResults["Data2"][0] = "Result";
    sensorResults["Data2"][1] = 700;
    sensorResults["Data3"][0] = "Result";
    sensorResults["Data3"][1] = 65.7;

    Vout = sensor.Sense();          // Sample data (read sensor)
    Tav  = sensor.GetAverageTemp(); // Calculate average temperature from N samples
    To   = sensor.GetLatestTemp();  // Calculate temperature from the latest sample

    //Serialize JSON
    s = sensorResults.serialize();
    //sl = s.size();

    //Print JSON string
    pc.printf("json: %s\r\n", s.c_str());

    //Convert JSON string to a char array to encrypt
    //char *a=new char[s.size()+1];
    a[s.size()]=0;
    memcpy(a,s.c_str(),s.size());

    //Print the char array to serial terminal
    pc.printf("\r\nJSON Char array");

    for(char i=0; i<s.size(); i++) 
    {
        if(i%16==0) pc.printf("\r\n");
        pc.printf("%.2X",s[i]);
    }

    AES myAES(AES_128, myKEY, myIV, CBC_MODE); // specify all params, look at BlockCipher.h for modes
    pc.printf("\r\n\r\nFirst run\r\n");
    myAES.encrypt(a,a,0x80); // same in and out buffer can be used
    pc.printf("\r\nEncrypted");
    for(char i=0; i<0x80; i++) 
    {
        //if(i%16==0) pc.printf("\r\n");
        pc.printf("%.2X",a[i]);
    }

    pc.printf("\r\nDecrypted again");
    myAES.decrypt(a,a,0x80);
    for(char i=0; i<0x80; i++) 
    {
        //if(i%16==0) pc.printf("\r\n");
        pc.printf("%.2X",a[i]);
    }

}
```

nodejs code:

```
var crypto = require("crypto")

function encrypt(key, data, iv) {
        var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
        var crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf-8', 'hex');
        crypted += cipher.final('hex');

        return crypted;
}

function decrypt(key, data, iv) {
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
        var decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf-8');
        decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');

        return decrypted;
}

var key = "mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsa";
var iv  = "asdfghjklpoiuytr";

var text = "{\"Data1\":[\"Result\",5.50],\"Data2\":[\"Result\",700],\"Data3\":[\"Result\",65.70]}";
console.log("Original Text: " + text);

var endata = "D90E1518FF2E5D79D6F848BCB4A49BCAE3ADDC6F1D6E04265613968CFF242855C10C619C8E281A33DA690039274AA65ECAFA05631C7BB38815442E780E27E34F2B6C4B9FE1B18678077227A05ACB233D8B8A81412E584A6ECAD10397FCF36072B043F93D67B63678A5D385B402D88AF99A62E12413E7BBFDB920B51F732C0933";
var decryptedText = decrypt(key, endata, iv);
console.log("Decrypted Text: " + decryptedText);
```

**UPDATE:**
I sent the C++ encrypted/unencrypted data to my serial terminal to see what the data looks like:

> json:
>   {"Data1":["Result",5.50],"Data2":["Result",700],"Data3":["Result",65.70]}
>
> JSON Char array 7B224461746131223A5B22526573756C
>   74222C352E35305D2C22446174613222 3A5B22526573756C74222C3730305D2C
>   224461746133223A5B22526573756C74 222C36352E37305D7D
>
> First run
>
> Encrypted
>   D90E1518FF2E5D79D6F848BCB4A49BCAE3ADDC6F1D6E04265613968CFF242855C10C619C8E281A33DA690039274AA65ECAFA05631C7BB38815442E780E27E34F2B6C4B9FE1B18678077227A05ACB233D8B8A81412E584A6ECAD10397FCF36072B043F93D67B63678A5D385B402D88AF99A62E12413E7BBFDB920B51F732C0933
>
> Decrypted again
>   7B224461746131223A5B22526573756C74222C352E35305D2C224461746132223A5B22526573756C74222C3730305D2C224461746133223A5B22526573756C74222C36352E37305D7D00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo No, Node.js is not working correctly.  Nodejs throws the "bad decrypt" error.

Comment: So that `endata` is what your C++ code is sending to the JS and `text` is what the input is supposed to be, right?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yes, endata is what my C++ code is sending to the JS and text is what the decrypted data should look like.  I will update my post to show what the C++ encrypted/unencrypted data should look like.

Comment: What crypto library are you using? Because it appears to be [this one](http://developer.mbed.org/users/feb11/code/Crypto/), but there is no ctor nor an `encrypt` method with such signature.

Comment: Yes I am using that crypto library.  I am also following this forum post which is in regards to that crypto library:  [http://developer.mbed.org/forum/libdev/topic/5094/](http://developer.mbed.org/forum/libdev/topic/5094/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your message is not padded, but Node's Decipher expects a [PKCS#7 padding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315#section-10.3) of the input and fails when none is found. Disable padding by calling [`Decipher.setAutoPadding()`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_decipher_setautopadding_auto_padding_true):

```
function decrypt(key, data, iv) {
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
        decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
        var decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf-8');
        decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');

        return decrypted;
}
```

Comment: I am still receiving the "bad decrypt" error  
`var endata = new Buffer("D90E1518FF2E5D79D6F848BCB4A49BCAE3ADDC6F1D6E04265613968CFF242855C10C619C8E281A33DA690039274AA65ECAFA05631C7BB38815442E780E27E34F2B6C4B9FE1B18678077227A05ACB233D8B8A81412E584A6ECAD10397FCF36072B043F93D67B63678A5D385B402D88AF99A62E12413E7BBFDB920B51F732C0933", "hex");
//var endatabuffer = new Buffer(endata, "hex");
var decryptedText = decrypt(key, endata, iv);
console.log("Decrypted Text: " + decryptedText);`

Comment: I copypasted the long enormous string.  It seems that the string was moved around so that it can fit in the comment area without having to scroll. [Here is an image of my IDE]http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img661/8391/HiIq9B.png

Comment: Yup... After some more checks, it appears that the issue was padding, the actual input is ok and you don't need the buffer (I should have read `update` docs).

Comment: That worked :-)  One more question, you mentioned: " 
What crypto library are you using? Because it appears to be this one, but there is no ctor nor an encrypt method with such signature." what did you mean when you wrote "there is no ctor"?

Comment: It's a abbreviation for constructor, you used a constructor for `AES` with 4 arguments, while [here](http://developer.mbed.org/users/feb11/code/Crypto/docs/f04410cef037/AES_8h_source.html) I see only one with 2 and one with 3. Maybe you are using a newer/older version of the lib.

Comment: I see, I was wrong when I replied that I was using that library.  I am using the updated version of the library found at:  http://developer.mbed.org/users/Geremia/code/Crypto/  
  
Anyways, this seems to be working on both mbed and nodejs side :-)